# How to reference a .NET assembly and provide its dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Sorry if this has been asked before but I'm struggling to work out how to phrase my question.

Essentially, I am developing a shared library that must depend on third-party vendor code - I want to ship this shared library through our internal NuGet server. However, the exact versions of the third-party library can vary based on the client's install.

What I want to do is provide a way for consumers of my library to:

- Reference my library via NuGet
- Select the exact version of the third-party library my library should depend on
- Either:

  - Not have to provide much binding code to do this, or
  - Be able to reference another library I provide that can handle the binding code

Is there a specific name for what I am trying to do, and does anyone know how I can do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package

Comment: @David I know how to create packages. What am I looking for here, specifically?

Comment: What do you want to differently than depending on a minimum version of a dependent nuget package?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I want the user to be able to choose the specific version to use. Just specifying a minimum version isn't enough because the dependency is responsible for interfacing with a third-party product, and the installed version of the third-party product varies from client to client.

Comment: The referencing project would be free to upgrade the reference at any time as long as the version range specified in your package allows it (default is just a minimum). NuGet / msbuild should be able to deal with binding redirect generation if necessary.